# Kotlin - Problems to read text of dinamically edit text

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I create a dynamically edit text. The first line is static, and is integrated on layout. Next lines are dynamically and your layout is in another xml.

[image]

I can read the value of first line (line static) but when the user touches on "next" option in the keyboard. I tried used the "addTextChangedListener" but the text appear like "o;on;one".

The dynamically lines I can't read the values.

Here's is my code:

```
/*Add Line*/
holder.add_field_button.setOnClickListener {
    holder.parent_linear_layout.apply {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        val rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.used_products_field, this, false)
        val rowViewDeleteButton = rowView.delete_button_din
        val readTextDin = rowView.number_edit_text_din

        holder.parent_linear_layout.addView(rowView, holder.parent_linear_layout.childCount!!)

        readTextDin.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->
                        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                            if (rowView.number_edit_text_din.text.isNotEmpty()) {
                                intervObject.Products += rowView.number_edit_text_din.text.toString() + ";"
                            }
                        }
                        false
                    }

        rowView.delete_button_din.setOnClickListener {
            holder.parent_linear_layout.removeView(it.parent as View)
        }

        //remove row
        removeField(holder.delete_button, holder.parent_linear_layout)
    }
}

/*First Line*/
holder.number_edit_text.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    holder.number_edit_text.clearFocus()
                    hideKeyboardFrom(context, holder.number_edit_text)

                    if (holder.number_edit_text.text.isNotEmpty()) {
                        intervObject.Products += holder.number_edit_text.text.toString() + ";"
                    }
                }
                false
}
```

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here

```
intervObject.Products += holder.number_edit_text.text.toString() + ";"
```

Every time you're changing it, you're adding the current text to this variable. So when it changes to `o`, you'll add `o;` and then when it changes to `on` you'll add `on;`

You could store it in a map instead, using the edittext as a key. That way everytime it changes, you'll only be replacing the value, not adding different versions!